# Trac configured to access Perforce repository?

Tags: plugins, perforce, trac, ticket-system

Have someone used with success TRAC ticketing + wiki system accessing a code base residing in Perforce repository?

I've browsed in the TRAC related web sites and found this [one](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/PerforcePlugin), but the latest change on the page is something like an year ago, so I have concluded (correct me if I'm wrong) that the plugin is hardly in working state OR that for some reason there is no recent developments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using Trac with Perforce, based on the PerforcePlugin you already mentioned. We have used the combination for about 1.5 years.

The plugin is basically stable enough for day-to-day work, but be prepared to fiddle with server memory allocation and have patience if working with large repositories.  Also, it has some irritating bugs, and as you have already noticed, development seems to have stalled completely.  In fairness it must be said that some of the bugs are due to shortcomings in Trac behaviuor and incompatability with "The Perforce Way".

Would I install Trac with Perforce again?  Probably not.  If forced to use Perforce, I would consider Redmine + Perforce.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to watch out for on Trac-hacks is the quantity and content of the open tickets for the plug-in.  The PerforcePlugin has a lot of [open tickets](http://trac-hacks.org/report/9?COMPONENT=PerforcePlugin).

Answer (score 0):

This update may help you: http://lynxline.com/tracperforce/, people got it working okay with Trac 1.0